# For the Same Data Set showing different data Type in MAC & Different in Colab

Tags: python, pandas, macos, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm Using Mac. In my mac I Install Anaconda. I used Jupiter notebook 6.1.4 in this to work on data. For Learning purpose, I'm using Kaggle SF Salaries Dataset(https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries).
After Importing the file in Jupyter Notebook & using the command df.info() it is showing specifications like this

```
>>>><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 148654 entries, 0 to 148653
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------            --------------   -----  
 0   Id                148654 non-null  int64  
 1   EmployeeName      148654 non-null  object 
 2   JobTitle          148654 non-null  object 
 3   BasePay           148049 non-null  object 
 4   OvertimePay       148654 non-null  object 
 5   OtherPay          148654 non-null  object 
 6   Benefits          112495 non-null  object 
 7   TotalPay          148654 non-null  float64
 8   TotalPayBenefits  148654 non-null  float64
 9   Year              148654 non-null  int64  
 10  Notes             0 non-null       float64
 11  Agency            148654 non-null  object 
 12  Status            38119 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(8)
memory usage: 14.7+ MB.
```

In the environment of colab same data set is showing different specifications.

```
>>>>>>>><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 116475 entries, 0 to 116474
Data columns (total 13 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------            --------------   -----  
 0   Id                116475 non-null  int64  
 1   EmployeeName      116475 non-null  object 
 2   JobTitle          116475 non-null  object 
 3   BasePay           115870 non-null  float64
 4   OvertimePay       116474 non-null  float64
 5   OtherPay          116474 non-null  float64
 6   Benefits          80315 non-null   float64
 7   TotalPay          116474 non-null  float64
 8   TotalPayBenefits  116474 non-null  float64
 9   Year              116474 non-null  float64
 10  Notes             0 non-null       float64
 11  Agency            116474 non-null  object 
 12  Status            5943 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(8), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 11.6+ MB.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/offYj.jpg)

Comment: please add the code concerning how you are loading the data both times, so we can spot the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is a csv file. The csv format is a plain text format: one line per row (normally delimited with a `'\r\n'`), each line containing fields separated with a delimiter (normally the comma `','`), and optionaly enclosed in quotes.

**But there is no indication for the datatypes**. Dumb tools (text editors or LibreOffice calc) present the raw data to the user, so that the user may choose the datatypes, delimiters and encoding. Clever tools (Excel and in some sense Collab or Pandas) think that they can *guess* everything, either because they decide from what they think common or with some heuristics. So there is no surprise that they end with different *guesses*.

(If you have not guessed it, I hate Excel handling of csv files, and only rely on calc...)